# How to get the following output using SQL SERVER 2008

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I need to implement a logic where I need to get the latest group data from a table .

Here is the example.

```
Result  Date

PASS    6/1/2016

PASS    6/2/2016

FAIL    6/10/2016

FAIL    6/11/2016

PASS    6/20/2016

PASS    6/21/2016

FAIL    7/1/2016

FAIL    7/5/2016

PASS    7/10/2016

PASS    7/11/2016
```

Required output

```
ID  Result  Date

    PASS    7/10/2016

    PASS    7/11/2016
```

Can you please help me?

Comment: What exactly do you need help with? Writing a SQL statement? How do you determine the output you requested? Are you selecting by ID? By date?

Comment: Output would be ID, using the Result only. Basically need to find out the latest group data.

Comment: Without showing your attempts the OP looks like "I want to have it done". -1

Comment: @ArnabPatra see solution below. If that's not correct I think you'll need to elaborate on your question

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
ID,
RESULT,
MAX(Date) as Date 
FROM Table 
GROUP BY ID, RESULT
```

The solution returns a single row for each ID and RESULT combination as noted by the GROUP BY clause. The row that is returned is the one which has the MAX date, aka the most current date even if it's in the future, with this pairing or grouping.

Comment: Code only response gives little to future readers. Please explain what do you mean.

Comment: @AlexKudryashev hope that's better. I'm on my mobile wasting time in a traffic jam....

Answer (score -2):

```
SELECT * FROM *table_name* WHERE ID IN (9, 10)
```

Comment: Hey Nick. Thanks for the response .It's actually not that simple. The ID will be the output and I need to find out using Result and Date as input. I have updated the question